# Problem of setting environment variables for installation of OpenFOAM-8

Tags: environment-variables, bashrc

I followed the instruction on website https://openfoam.org/download/8-source/ to install OpenFOAM-8 with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, every step was great until the setting of environment variables. Like the website instructed I tried to add the following code to $HOME/.bashrc file, this was what I done:

```
  vim .bashrc
```

and then added these code into bashrc file at the bottom,

```
  source $HOME/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-8/etc/bashrc
```

Here is where I felt somthing wrong...Without any indications or prompts after I finished. I then saved and quit the vim, and type this in the terminal window, nothing happened also:

```
  source $HOME/.bashrc
```

I just followed the instruction and moved to the compiling of OpenFOAM section, I typed ./Allwmake in OpenFOAM-8 directory it gived me:

```
  ./Allwmake: 22: ./Allwmake make: not found
```

I also tried sudo ./Allwmake, it gived me:

```
  Allwmake error: The OpenFOAM environment is not set.
     Check the OpenFOAM entries in your dot-files and source them.
```

So I think the problem must in the setting environment variables section. Could anyone tell me how to solve this please?

Comment: `make: not found` so is the `make` package installed on your system?

Comment: The required package was installed in OpenFOAM-8 directory isn't it? As the instruction said I only need to compile OpenFOAM by excuting the Allwmake script. Or is my OpenFOAM-8 file incomplete? Should I try to download it again?

Comment: Please install `m4` (i.e. `sudo apt install m4` or equivalent from the GUI package manager) and then try `./Allwmake` again

Comment: Still the same. Any other suggestions?

Comment: What exactly is "still the same"? You report 2 issues: (1) `make: not found` and (2) `Allwmake error: The OpenFOAM environment is not set.` when you try to execute `./Allwmake` with `sudo`. The latter is expected behavior because you sourced the modified .bashrc into your own environment, not root's

Comment: Both  ./Allwmake  and  sudo ./Allwmake  still give me the same output, which is "make not found" and "Allwmake error: The OpenFOAM environment is not set." Do you mean that the problem is not related to the environment variables setting? What should I do? I am a novice in Ubuntu, please forgive me...

Comment: Apologies - I somehow read that as `m4: not found`. Please confirm that the `make` package is installed.

Comment: I open OpenFOAM-8 directory and type ls, I see a green directory called Allwmake. Does that means the make package was installed?

Comment: No - I meant something like `apt policy make` and/or `type -a make`

Comment: I will try to figure it out. Thank you very much!